# How to exclude child in Python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I wrote a script in python to get the prices of products in a website, but I found a problem. Sometimes some products are on sale, because of that they have 2 prices (the original and the actual). My scripts get all of them, but I don't want the prices before the sale. How can I exclude them? Is it possible?

Example in source-code:

Normal price

```
 <div class="result-actions"
   <span> ==$0
     $ 1,98
   </span>
```

On sale

```
 <div class="result-actions">
   <span>
     <small class="price-before"> ==$0
       $ 56,70
     </small>
     <span class="price-now">
       $ 39,60
     </span>
   </span>
```

My script

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = input()
html = urlopen(site)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
pricesList = bs.findAll('div',{'class':'result-actions'})
csvFile = open('Prices.csv', 'wt+')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)


try:
  for prices in pricesList:
    print(clean_up_text(prices.get_text()))
    csvPrice = []
    csvPrice.append(clean_up_text(prices.get_text().strip()))
    writer.writerow(csvPrice)                  
finally:
  csvFile.close()
```

Please, help me!

## Update

I tried to include a function to exclude the older prices, but it seems won't work too.

```
def excluir_precos_antigos(element):
  element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('price-before')
    driver.execute_script("""var element = 
    arguments[0];element.parentNode.removeChild(element);""", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find the `span` tag storing the sale price:

```
d = """
<div class="result-actions">
 <span>
  <small class="price-before"> ==$0
   $ 56,70
  </small>
  <span class="price-now">
   $ 39,60
  </span>
</span>
</div>
"""
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
result = soup(d, 'html.parser').find('span', {'class':'price-now'}).text
```

Output:

```
'\n   $ 39,60\n  '
```

If there are multiple `result-actions` `div`s on the page, you can use `find_all`:

```
final_results = [i.find('span', {'class':'price-now'}).text for i in soup(d, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'result-actions'})]
```

Which gives all sale prices on the page:

```
['\n   $ 39,60\n  ']
```

Comment: Hello Ajax, thank you for your help! But I don't think it'll work like I hope, because the products that aren't on sale won't appear in the output. Can I put a conditional to not include the "prices-before" ?